# When Merge null columns are not merged just inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table and it's data are below

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (Id int ITDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,stateid int, district int Sitecount int)

CREATE TABLE Sales1(stateid int, district int,
Sitecount Int)

insert into Sales values (1,2,12)
insert into Sales values (1,3,20)
insert into Sales values (1, NULL, 10) 
insert into Salesi values (1,2,10) 
insert into Salesi values (1,2. 100) 
insert into Select values (1,ULL, 18)
```

I have used the below query to merge

```
MERGE Sales AS T 
USING (Select stateid, district, Sitecount from Sales1 group by stateid,district) as S
 ON(S.stateid =T.stateld and S.district=T.district) 
 WHEN MATCHED
Then UPDATE SET
T.Sitecount=T.Sitecount+S.Sitecount 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (stateid,district,Sitecount) VALUES(S stateid, S.district, S.5itecount);
```

Whenever I run the query, if the matched data all columns are not null then only data merged,
Otherwise it is inserted as a new row.

If district data is null, need to add the sitecount based on the stateid.How to achieve it. Suggest me..

Comment: `NULL = NULL` does not equal true, it equals unknown. If you have `NULL` values you must handle them appropriately. For example `WHERE (Col1 = Col2 OR (Col1 IS NULL and Col2 IS NULL))`

Comment: um - your avatar is a quote from Hitler? You REALLY might want to reconsider that.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu. Your hint is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MERGE Sales AS T 
USING (Select stateid, district, Sitecount from Sales1 group by stateid,district) as S
 ON(ISNULL(S.stateid, -1) = ISNULL(T.stateld, -1) and ISNULL(S.district, '')= ISNULL(T.district, '')) 
 WHEN MATCHED
Then UPDATE SET
T.Sitecount=T.Sitecount+S.Sitecount 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (stateid,district,Sitecount) VALUES(S stateid, S.district, S.5itecount);
```

The following element was adjusted to isnull the comparison fields as a null value as you have observed are treated differently and incorrectly (for what you desire) execute the insert element:

```
 ON(ISNULL(S.stateid, -1) = ISNULL(T.stateld, -1) and ISNULL(S.district, '')= ISNULL(T.district, ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match on `stateid` using `ISNULL` in `join` like below:

```
MERGE Sales AS T 
USING (Select stateid, district, max(Sitecount) Sitecount from Sales1 group by stateid,district) as S
 ON(S.stateid =T.stateid and isnull(S.district,'')=isnull(T.district, '')) 
 WHEN MATCHED
Then UPDATE SET
T.Sitecount=T.Sitecount+S.Sitecount

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (stateid,district,Sitecount) VALUES(S.stateid, S.district, S.Sitecount);

select * from Sales
```

Also, please note that I have used `max(Sitecount)` to avoid the duplicates in `join`. Please change as per your requirement.

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ea8170f6216e918a44a90e875cc1829)**.

Comment: We must have clicked "add comment" at the same time. I can assure you my answer wasn't a "copy paste"

Comment: @Raymondo yeah, same here :). I think you posted first.

Comment: @Raymondo Thanks! did the same :)

Comment: I am also give +1 to both of you. Thanks for your help

Comment: @KarthickRamu Thanks! you can accept the answer too so that all can know that the question is answered correctly.

Comment: Flip a coin. Heads @sacse, tails me  and glad we helped out